# Can't launch Cassandra on a t2.micro(free tier) instance - connection error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cassandra

Is it not possible to launch Cassandra on a t2.micro (free tier)? I am getting an error:

```
nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - 
ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'.
```

I have tried a couple of solutions from SO

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS - Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1" 

Restarting the service: sudo service cassandra restart

If you have a cluster, make sure that ports 7000 and 9042 are 
open within your security group.
```

This is not an issue on a t2.medium instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, This is because **[T2.micro](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/)** has 1GB RAM and have 1 core only, which does not fulfil the [minimum requirements](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/hardware.html) of Cassandra.

It should work on T2.Medium because It has

```
t2.medium   2(VCPU) 4(Memory)
```

**Hardware Choices**

> Like most databases, Cassandra throughput improves with more CPU
>   cores, more RAM, and faster disks. While Cassandra can be made to run
>   on small servers for testing or development environments (including
>   Raspberry Pis), a minimal production server requires at least 2 cores,
>   and at least 8GB of RAM. Typical production servers have 8 or more
>   cores and at least 32GB of RAM.

**CPU**

> Cassandra is highly concurrent, handling many simultaneous requests
>   (both read and write) using multiple threads running on as many CPU
>   cores as possible. The Cassandra write path tends to be heavily
>   optimized (writing to the commitlog and then inserting the data into
>   the memtable), so writes, in particular, tend to be CPU bound.
>   Consequently, adding additional CPU cores often increases throughput
>   of both reads and writes.

**Memory**

> Cassandra runs within a Java VM, which will pre-allocate a fixed size
>   heap (java’s Xmx system parameter). In addition to the heap, Cassandra
>   will use significant amounts of RAM offheap for compression metadata,
>   bloom filters, row, key, and counter caches, and an in process page
>   cache. Finally, Cassandra will take advantage of the operating
>   system’s page cache, storing recently accessed portions files in RAM
>   for rapid re-use.

**The Cassandra heap should be no less than 2GB, and no more than 50% of your system RAM**